# How to align authors and title in beamer title page?

Tags: beamer, titles, beamer-metropolis

I would like to add multiple authors with their affiliations in columns in the beamer title page. I am using the metropolis theme.

It almost works, but the aligment with the first author should be with the title and the orange line. The three authors should be arranged evenly through the orange line. How can I do this? Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{Title of the paper}%
\author{%
\texorpdfstring{
\begin{columns}
\column{.33\textwidth}
Author 1\\
Inst 1
\column{.33\textwidth}
Author 2\\
Inst 2
\column{.33\textwidth}
Author 3\\
Inst 3
\end{columns}
}{Authors}}%

\date{February 2023}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]%
\titlepage%  
\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```

[image: titlepage]

Comment: You need `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]`.  Actually, this makes the text area wider rather than the columns narrower, but at least they match.

Comment: Nice and simple! Thank you. Would a wider text area make the title slide format different from the rest of the presentation? Do you want to write an answer simply with the addition of the option [onlytextwidth]?

Comment: `onlytextwidth` can also be used as a Beamer option (whole document).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a one line patch (onlytextwidth).

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{Title of the paper}%
\author{%
\texorpdfstring{
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column{0.33\textwidth}
Author 1\\
Inst 1
\column{0.33\textwidth}
Author 2\\
Inst 2
\column{0.33\textwidth}
Author 3\\
Inst 3
\end{columns}
}{Authors}}%

\date{February 2023}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]%
\titlepage%  
\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Great! Did you expected to use `\tempdima` for something?

Comment: Oops, old experiment.

Comment: Great. I though `onlytextwidth` was a class option and didn't it could be used here.

Comment: See page 125 of the Beamer manual.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use own-build `columns` environment instead multiple native authors listing?

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{Title of the paper}%
\author{
Author 1\inst{1}
\and
Author 2\inst{2}
\and
Author 3\inst{3}
}
\institute{
\inst{1}Inst 1
\and
\inst{2}Inst 2
\and
\inst{3}Inst 3
}
\date{February 2023}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]%
\titlepage%  
\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```

I know it doesn't answer your question but authors and institutes lists are used elsewhere (think about footers and headers etc.)

if you really want to use your own columns, build your own title frame like (not tested)

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{Title of the paper}%
\date{February 2023}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]%
\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
\bigskip
\begin{columns}
\column{.33\textwidth}
Author 1\\
Inst 1
\column{.33\textwidth}
Author 2\\
Inst 2
\column{.33\textwidth}
Author 3\\
Inst 3
\end{columns}
\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```

Finally, you may want to add some empty box in front of some names with for example `~Author A` or `\fbox{\phantom{foo}}Author A` etc.

Comment: I prefer to list the institutes just below the authors instead of adding a footnote. It looks better. Adding the empy box is a good suggestion, but I prefer to use something automatic instead of trying to calculate the necessary space.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think there's always a little calculation involved (e.g. `.33\textwidth` instead of an automatic equal distribution…) Maybe that should be done once with a first empty column then?

Comment: Yes. It is better to use something that applies in general instead of adding spaces for the specific situation.